# Insert text into a file (.bat) as well as increase a number sequentially

Tags: powershell, batch-file

For instance, I am creating reboot scripts for about 400 servers to reboot every night. I already have the task scheduler portion done with a script.

What I need is, how to insert "shutdown /r /m \servername-001 /f" into a file called "servername-001_Reboot.bat".
and in the same script change the 001 to 002 into the next batch file and so on and so forth.

Unless someone has a more efficient way of doing an automated reboot schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Have a variable `$ServerNumber = 1` and inside your for-loop just keep incrementing it.

The filename for the batchfile can be made like so:

`$filename = "servername-$( "{0:D3}" -f $ServerNumber )_Reboot.bat"`

(Read [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692795.aspx) to learn more about formatting numbers in powershell)

Any variable including a string, let's call it `$str`, can be piped to any file:

`$str | Out-File "path/to/file/$filename"`

use the `-Append` flag if you want to append data to the file if it already exists (as opposed to overwriting it).